# Rails nomethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and am trying to create an application that takes a user request. However this is what is happening when I am trying to create a new request.

**Request Controller:**

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /requests
  # GET /requests.json
  def index
    @requests = Request.all
  end

  # GET /requests/1
  # GET /requests/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /requests/new
  def new
    @request = Request.new

  end

  # GET /requests/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /requests
  # POST /requests.json
  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save # <-------------- The problem is here
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1
  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.update(request_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /requests/1
  # DELETE /requests/1.json
  def destroy
    @request.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to requests_url, notice: 'Request was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_request
      @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:user_id, :description, :created)
    end
end
```

The error says there is no "Create" method in the requests controller, however the method that is saying this is the create method. I think that a problem is that my view isn't passing the description as a parameter and I'm not sure how to do that/why it's not already.

**_form.html.erb (Rendered by edit.html.erb):**

```
%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>
  <% if @request.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@request.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this request from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @request.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <center>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Describe your favor' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  </center>
<% end %>
```

If someone could show me how to pass the description object as a parameter to my create method and get the method to not crash.

**Here is the error log:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `Request' for #<Request:0x007f9fbd8992e8>):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:32:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:31:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (29.4ms)
```

Comment: The error doesn't say that there's no `create` method. It says there's no method named `Request`. What is the value of `request_params`?

Comment: It should be the `:description` that the user submits. It's used as `@request = Request.new(request_params)`

Comment: If things were always as they should be, we would never have bugs. What is the *actual* value?

Comment: It's not getting a value passed to it from the form.html.erb.

Answer (score 2):

Using Request (or Response) as the name of a model is not a very good idea since you will end up shadowing the [request object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html). Which is a core part of Rails controllers.

It will also make it very confusing to reason about your code since it will collide with a core concept in MVC and web development in general.

Use a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/request) and find another name for your model.

Comment: If you really have to use `Request` then call your variable `@the_request` and always resolve it from the base namespace `::Request` to avoid collisions. But that just stinks of poor design.